# Avoid "duplicate" borders using display: inline-block

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-tables

I'm doing some research (maybe it's not the appropriate word) with div's behavior when used as a table.

**Spoiler alert**: this is why I want to do this. If you are not interested just go ahead :)

I want to achieve a full working table without using the `table`element and avoiding the use of `display: table, [...]` properties. This because (I'm not crazy yet, I guess) I found out that the `table` are not suitable for my project and the `display: table` properties family gives me so many issues when it comes to styling... 
I found out that some major SaaS nowaday are using divs instead of tables (Google Sheets, Excel Online, Airtable, my project) and I'm trying to achieve the same result. For reasons. **(end of the spoiler)**

Well, I came out to a pretty satisfying code snippet with a pretty annoying issue: **duplicate borders** when using `display: inline-block`;

I'm pretty sure that a picture can better explain what I mean:

[image]

I can also provide a **fiddle** here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lc0rE/j2obdh0h/

And here we have the code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="table-container">
  <div class="row-container">
    <div class="cell">Cell1</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell2</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell2</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell3</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell4</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.table-container {
  width: 700px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #fefefe;
}

.row-container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #fff;
  height: 30px;
}

.cell-header {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.cell {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-left: 5px;
  min-width: 100px;
  /* ;
  border-left: 1px solid #dde1e3;
  border-right: 1px solid transparent;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent; */
  border: 1px solid #dde1e3;
  top: 0;
  overflow: visible;
}

.cell:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid #dde1e3;
}

.row-container:last-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dde1e3;
}

.selected {
  border: 1px solid #00b9e6 !important;
  background: #EBF7FF !important;
}

.cell-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

I really hope someone could help me to solve this annoying issue.
I'm also open to every suggestion on different ways to implement this!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/j2obdh0h/1/ Something like this?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The fiddle works like a charm! Just the selected class is not working as expected when a click event occurs on a cell. I guess I need to apply the same border rules you show me?

Comment: `display: inline-block` Doesn't cause double borders. There are two borders because each cell has its own borders. The previous comment should work (only give top/right border to each cell).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to draw the borders separately to avoid the double borders. For highlight style, I use absolute positioned pseudo elements for two sides of the borders.

```js
$(".cell").click(function() {
  $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
  $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", "sans-serif";
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.table-container {
  width: 650px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #fefefe;
}

.row-container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #fff;
  height: 30px;
}

.cell-header {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.cell {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-left: 5px;
  min-width: 100px;
  border-left: 1px solid #dde1e3;
  border-top: 1px solid #dde1e3;
  top: 0;
  overflow: visible;
}

.row-container .cell:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid #dde1e3;
}

.row-container:last-child .cell {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dde1e3;
}

.selected {
  position: relative;
  background: #EBF7FF;
  border-left: 1px solid blue;
  border-top: 1px solid blue;
}

.selected:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  bottom: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  border-right: 1px solid blue;
}

.selected:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1px;
  left: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}

.cell-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.draggable {
  position: relative;
  right: -7px;
  width: 12px;
  opacity: .3;
  height: 28px
}

.dragbar {
  position: relative;
  right: -4px;
  width: 4px;
  opacity: 1;
  height: 28px;
}

.dragbar:hover {
  background: blue;
  opacity: .6;
  cursor: ew-resize;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-container">
  <div class="row-container">
    <div class="cell cell-header">
      <div class="cell-content">
        <span>Cell</span>
        <div class="draggable">
          <div class="dragbar"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell cell-header">
      <div class="cell-content">
        <span>Cell</span>
        <div class="draggable">
          <div class="dragbar"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell cell-header">
      <div class="cell-content">
        <span>Cell</span>
        <div class="draggable">
          <div class="dragbar"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell cell-header">
      <div class="cell-content">
        <span>Cell</span>
        <div class="draggable">
          <div class="dragbar"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell cell-header">
      <div class="cell-content">
        <span>Cell</span>
        <div class="draggable">
          <div class="dragbar"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell cell-header">
      <div class="cell-content">
        <span>Cell</span>
        <div class="draggable">
          <div class="dragbar"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="row-container">
    <div class="cell selected">Cell1</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell2</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell2</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell3</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell4</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-container">
    <div class="cell">Cell1</div>
    <div class="cell">Cel2312312l2</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell2</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell3</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell4</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-container">
    <div class="cell">Cell1</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell2</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell2</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell3</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell4</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-container">
    <div class="cell">Cell1</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell2</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell2</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell3</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell4</div>
    <div class="cell">Cell5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
.cell { 
    border-left: 1px solid red;
}
.cell:last-child {
    border-right: 1px solid red;
}
.row-container {
   border-top: 1px solid blue;
}
.row-container:last-child {
   border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
 }
```

[**revised fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/j2obdh0h/5/)

Comment: Thanks @Micheal_B for your answer. It works well till I try to apply the border to the .selected class. When I select a cell the width changes slightly.

Comment: Can you post an updated fiddle that shows the problem?